# CSS Flexbox: what is the (algorithm for / definition of) "hypothetical cross size"?

Tags: css, flexbox

From the specification, almost everything in the layout algorithm is defined, but this item seems to be missing.

Paragraph 9.4.7: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-cross-item - says:

> "Determine the hypothetical cross size of each item by performing
>   layout with the used main size and the available space, treating auto
>   as fit-content."

However "performing layout" is undefined -- it's what this paragraph is supposed to define, and instead it just ... recursively defines itself?

By contrast, the previous section (for Main Size) explicitly defines the algorithm for "perform layout". But the algorithms for Main and Cross must necessarily (almost by definition?) be (at least slightly!) different.

I'm debugging some detailed Flexbox code, and questions over "what, exactly, is the correct behaviour for cross-size layout?" are proving difficult to answer when I can't find an unambiguous section of the spec for this.

Comment: Have you tried googling other definitions? Like here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/flexbox-the-ultimate-css-flex-cheatsheet/#terminology

Comment: It may help to illustrate the problem by posting some of that code you're trying to debug.

Comment: @Justinas I see nothing in that link that goes into any detail of algorithm of specification - could you be more specific? Maybe I'm looking at the wrong part of the page? It appears be a largely superficial treatment of simplified layout situations. That's fine for someone who just wants a basic intro - but no value when trying to understand the actual algorithm in detail.

Comment: @Michael_B Without a specification, I have no way of saying which of the many thousands of lines of code are correct or incorrect: all I can do is guess. If I can understand / find the missing specifciation detail, then I can start pulling out individual pieces of code that are incorrect and solving them one by one.

Comment: Can you at least describe the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Well from that link I see that if `main size` is width, then `cross size` is height. Or in other words size between `cross start` and `cross end`

Comment: @justinas Fine, but ... what is "height" when there is no height (most of the time: there isn't one)? How do you resolve percentage heights - is the available-space the flexline-space, the pre-flexline-expansion-space, the post-flexline-expansion-space, the container-space, or ... something else? (I appreciate these may be dumb/obvious questions, but from the spec: I can't figure out the canonical, correct, interpretation)

Comment: @Michael_B Slight paraphrase for brevity, but: "in complex nested flexboes, wrapped items don't always fit the cross size as expected, and/or containers don't always fit their (wrapped) childitems as expected - but non-wrapped items fit exactly as expected". Non-wrapped items are much more precisely defined in the spec, so that one was probably easier to code in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, and with extensive testing in browsers, I came to the conclusion it means something like:

> Do the undefined, arbitrary, parts of this specification, in whatever way you - the implementer - think is 'good'

i.e. there isn't a specification here. (officially: 'whatever the browsers do' is correct, but of course: what they do changes over time, and has its own bugs)

In particular: there's a big hole in CSS spec, which is "what is the size of an element?"; it's explicitly unexplicit, with 'suggestions' offered for what the sizes of various elements 'might' be. e.g. a PNG image could, perhaps, use its raw pixel width and height (but should you be following retina sizes, real sizes, points vs pixels, etc? And what should an SVG do? There's several arguably-correct answers to each of these).

... which I think is why the spec leaves this space blank.

Ultimately I found the best results by implementing a sensible set of heuristics for intrinsic sizes for elements, then using them here with the available meta info, constraints, etc. This fit most closely with what browsers were doing, and gives good results.